# How to write the extensions values as unnamed property within the Swagger generated by SpringFox?

Tags: spring, swagger, openapi, springfox, swagger-3.0

I added in [my code](https://github.com/educostadev/springfoxdemo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/springfoxdemo/config/SpringFoxConfig.java) a [vendor extension](https://swagger.io/specification/#vendorExtensions) named `x-my-test` using the **extensions** method from the [ApiInfo](https://github.com/educostadev/springfoxdemo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/springfoxdemo/config/SpringFoxConfig.java) class:

```
new ApiInfoBuilder()
        ...
        .extensions(List.of(
         new ListVendorExtension<>("x-my-test", List.of("myvalue"))
         )).build();
```

And the [yaml file](https://github.com/educostadev/springfoxdemo/blob/master/swagger-openapi.yaml) generated shows this value within the property *extensions* as follow:

```
  ...     
  version: 1;2021-02-01
  extensions:
    x-my-test:
      - myvalue
  ...
```

I noticed that if I load this [yaml file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/educostadev/springfoxdemo/master/swagger-openapi.yaml) into the [Swagger Editor](https://editor.swagger.io) then I can see an error due to the *extensions* property:

```
Structural error at info
should NOT have additional properties
additionalProperty: extensions
```

**Is it possible to write the `x-my-test` value outside the *extensions* property ?**

and have an output like this:

```
  ...     
  version: 1;2021-02-01
  x-my-test:
    - myvalue
  ...
```

This output matches the swagger specification and it loads with success in swagger editor.